# Custom Css for Each Language - Qtranslate X

Tags: javascript, php

I installed Qtranslate X wordpress plugin to make a multilingual site. It works great but I have one problem.. My website information is on english language(default) and this information is using english specific handwriting font , which doesn't supports cyrilic alphabet so I want to add custom css for font families for russian language. Is it possible ? Maybe someone used this plugin before? I searched information and found one topic but its old and this guy is posting stuff like this

```
`I found something which worked!
Using the lang selector:
:lang(ja){
/* Japanese-only styles */
}
:lang(en){
/* English-only styles */
}
```

Maybe someone can help me with this, where put this code in functions php or? S

I need totally different styles fo each language if for ENGLISH LANGUAGE it is :
.wrapper {font-family:pompiere;}

FOR RUSSIAN it have to be :

.wrapper {font-family:russian;}

Thanks guys and will be happy for answer

Comment: That code is CSS and you would have to add it to your CSS files or to a `<style>` element in the page.

Comment: THANKS BRO !!! <3 IT WORKS ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy, you only need to change the template, in the "body" tag (for example) you can add this:

```
<body class="<?php print qtrans_getLanguage(); ?> other_class">
```

now you can use a body.en, body.ru, body.fr or any language css selector:

```
body.ru .wrapper { font-family: russian; }
```